# How to handle (discrete) time-series of boundary condition in Bayesian estimation of ODE?

Tags: bayesian, winbugs

I want to estimate the parameter in an ordinary differential equation (ODE). However, I don’t know how to input the time series of the boundary condition. It is not a “function”, but a time series (i.e., discrete data points). For example, daily inflow of water when modelling water volume of a lake.

I checked the manual of WinBUGS Differential interface, and it seems that their "Worked Example 2: Population PK Model" offers a solution, which is by `ode.block()` and `piecewise()` function:

```
    R31[i] <- piecewise(vec.R31[i, 1:n.block])                              
    vec.R31[i, 1] <- 0                              
    vec.R31[i, 2] <- 0                              
    vec.R31[i, 3] <- dose[i] / TI[i]                            
    vec.R31[i, 4] <- 0      
    
    ...
    list(
         ... n.block = 4, ...)
```

where `R31[i]` can be seen as a time-variable boundary condition, `n.block` means that there are four sub-period for this boundary condition.

However, this solution can not be applied in my model, since I have a boundary condition whose data can not be divided into only 4 (or several) periods. The boundary condition is a daily-scale time series. Thus, if the simulation is 10 years, then I have 3650 sub-periods.

Is there a way to handle the numeric (i.e., discrete) boundary condition with many data points?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools (*a software*), software libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic according to the [help] guidelines.

Comment: @KenWhite Hi Ken, I have clarified my question whose focus is on the procedure of discrete boundary condition, not a specific software. I suppose this question can be helpful to the community because a discrete (e.g., from observed time series) boundary condition is common, and in many cases this problem is circumvented by fitting it as a smooth function (e.g., a sin() function).

Comment: I've retracted my close vote. Please remember my previous comment for future reference here. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks Ken! I will keep it in mind :)